# Pandas custom file format

Tags: pandas, bigdata

I have a huge Pandas DataFrame that I need to write away to a format that RankLib can understand. Example with a target, a query ID and 3 features is this:

```
5 qid:4 1:12 2:0.6 3:13
1 qid:4 1:8 2:0.4 3:11
```

I have written my own function that iterates over the rows and writes them away like this:

```
data_file = open(filename, 'w')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    line = str(row['score'])
    line += ' qid:'+str(row['srch_id'])
    counter = 0
    for feature in feature_columns:
        counter += 1
        line += ' '+str(counter)+':'+str(row[feature])
    data_file.write(line+'\n')
data_file.close()
```

Since I have about 200 features and 5m rows this is obviously very slow. Is there a better approach using the I/O of Pandas itself?

Comment: You could just add the desired output as a new column and then write just that column out

Comment: That is a nice solution however that's not going to fit in my memory anymore...

Comment: what is `counter` in your code?

Comment: I snipped off a bit too much, let me add it back, it's to count the features, which need to be named (in my case 1..N)

Comment: What's the original dataframe (`data`) that leads to the output you posted?

Comment: It's an Expedia dataset from Kaggle that has been preprocessed quite a bit, training set has about 200 features, test set same (no target), both around 5m rows

Comment: You could try iterating over chunks with `df.iloc[i:i+5000]` and using EdChum's approach, hopefully without running out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

Data:

```
In [155]: df
Out[155]:
   f1   f2  f3 score  srch_id
0  12  0.6  13     5        4
1   8  0.4  11     1        4
2  11  0.7  14     2       10

In [156]: df.dtypes
Out[156]:
f1           int64
f2         float64
f3           int64
score       object
srch_id      int64
dtype: object
```

Solution:

```
feature_columns = ['f1','f2','f3']
cols2id = {col:str(i+1) for i,col in enumerate(feature_columns)}

def f(x):
    if x.name in feature_columns:
        return cols2id[x.name] + ':' + x.astype(str)
    elif x.name == 'srch_id':
        return 'quid:' + x.astype(str)
    else:
        return x

(df.apply(lambda x: f(x))[['score','srch_id'] + feature_columns]
  .to_csv('d:/temp/out.csv', sep=' ', index=False, header=None)
)
```

out.csv:

```
5 quid:4 1:12 2:0.6 3:13
1 quid:4 1:8 2:0.4 3:11
2 quid:10 1:11 2:0.7 3:14
```

`cols2id` helper dict:

```
In [158]: cols2id
Out[158]: {'f1': '1', 'f2': '2', 'f3': '3'}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this apply also runs out of memory, I have decided to just suck it up and write it row by row (it's at 10%). Nice solution though!